# Android Studio issue when importing the project from windows to mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am trying to import my Android project from my pc with windows to my mac ( OSX ) and I get the following error when the project is gradlleing:

[image: This is the error]

So, do you have any idea why is that? I can import projects from Mac to my Windows but when I do from my Windows to Mac I get this error....

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and check if you have something like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

If not just add the above to the end of the file.